# ¿Cómo dibujar la distribución t?

Tags: r, rstudio

Quisiera dibujar la distribucion en t con su sobreado y cortes de H0 y H1 en R studio, a continuacion es lo que me arrojo el `t.test`n=3705, n.s = 0.05  por favor ayudarme, gracias.

```
data:  data$edad by data$independentismo
t = 1.1584, df = 3430.8, p-value = 0.2468
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -0.4494652  1.7475706
sample estimates:
mean in group No independentista    mean in group Independentista 
                        52.22440                         51.57535
```

Comment: Hola Victor, puse una respuesta, pero me quedó una duda ¿tu prueba es en la cola positiva de la distribución en las dos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Van dos opciones, una usando una librería y otra a mano (derivada del código en esa librería). El problema es que no me coinciden los estadísticos que calculo usando la distribución con lo que obtienes en tu prueba, ver al final.

## `sjPlot`

En este caso la librería `sjPlot::` tiene la función `dist_t()` toma como argumentos los grados de libertad, el valor `t` de la prueba y (opcionalmente) el nivel alfa de la decisión (criterio de corte del p-value). **Grafica solamente pruebas en una sola cola.**

En tu caso podrías usar:

```
 dist_t(deg.f = 3430, #Los grados de libertad de la distribución
            p = 1) +  #Para pintar toda el área de rechazo
   geom_vline(xintercept = 1.15)  #Para marcar el valor t que salió de tu test
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Es muy simple y esa librería permite hacer lo mismo con diferentes distribuciones. Eso sí, tienes unas dependencias muy pesadas (carga muchísimos otros paquetes en la instalación).

## A mano

Si buscas una solución más personalizada https://github.com/strengejacke/sjPlot/blob/master/R/sjPlotDist.R está el código de la función, que podrías adaptar a tus necesidades (sobre todo el cálculo de los cuantiles)

En este caso se grafica una prueba t en ambas colas de las distribución.

De hecho revisando ese código hice esta adaptación al problema:

```
# Crear los datos de una dist t con df grados de libertad
library(tidyverse)

df <- 3430.8  #Grados de libertad en la distribución T

t_max <- stats::qt(p = 0.00001, df = df, lower.tail = F)  #Valor de T para un evento muy poco probable. Indica hasta dónde vamos a dibujar la curva. 

t_alfa <- 1-qt(p = 0.05, df = df)    # El valor T para el p-value que usamos como alfa, asumo que 0.05

p_value <- pt(q = 1.1584, df = df, lower.tail = F)*2  #Solo para verificar que corresponde con el resultado de la prueba

t_observado <- 1.1584

para_t <- tibble(
                 x = seq(-t_max, t_max, length.out = 1000 * t_max),  #Creo una secuencia usando el intervalo de mínimo y máximo 
                 y = dt(x, df= df),                                #Encuentro la densidad en la distribución T para esa secuencia
                 alfa = ifelse(x >= t_alfa | x <= -t_alfa, "Es posible rechazar H0",  #Esto es para colorear después
                               "No es posible rechazar H0"))


ggplot(para_t, aes(x = x, y = y )) + 
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymax = y, ymin = 0, fill = alfa)) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = t_observado) +  #Dibujo una línea en el valor T observado
  geom_text(x = t_observado-0.1,          #Lo muevo para que no se superponga con la línea
            y = 0.2,                      #Como a la mitad de y, ajustar a ojo
            label = "T observado = 1.15", 
            angle = 90) + 
  theme(legend.position = "bottom")
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Disculpa no se que me paso, el estudio es a 2 colas al 95% de confianza, y muchas gracias.

Comment: Ya está actualizada. Ahora sí coinciden todos los estadísticos (t, p, t|alfa, etc)